# Is there a way to store previous response and compare to current?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I usually google my questions but couldn't really find any this time. I'm not really into programming either, just trying.

So basically I'm trying to do a script that constantly does GET request to html page, get the content, store it for some time and then get another request, compare response contect with previous and do different actions based on condition, if they're equal - do nothing, if they're different - perform new action.
Here is the code I wrote. I understand WHY it's not working, it does both requests at the same time. I just can't figure out how to store it properly.

```
import requests
import time

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
result = requests.request("GET", url, verify=True)
new_result = requests.request("GET", url, verify=True)

print(result.content)
print(new_result.content)

while result.content == new_result.content:
        print('condition 1')
        time.sleep(15)

while result.content != new_result.content:
        print('condition 2')
        time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. I've replaced your 2 loops with just one (infinite for now, but you can always change that to suit your actual requirements). The key is to do the `sleep` before getting the `new_result`, then check whether it's equal to the old one. And then finally update the "old" one to be the result you just fetched.

```
import requests
import time

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
result = requests.request("GET", url, verify=True)

while True:
    time.sleep(15)
    new_result = requests.request("GET", url, verify=True)
    print(result.content)
    print(new_result.content)
    if result.content == new_result.content:
        print('condition 1')
    else:
        print('condition 2')
    result = new_result
```